# How do I write a Microsoft Word/Office Open XML document using Perl?

Tags: perl, ms-word, openxml, opendocument

I have written a Perl script that reads some data and generates an OpenOffice Writer/OpenDocument file for that data. Can I also construct a Microsoft Word/Office Open XML document?

Comment: I'm sure you mean OpenXML. There is no such thing as *OpenOffice Word*.

Comment: @0xA3, I think he means a Word document in OpenOffice(.org).

Comment: @0xA3:That is what I meant. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read MS Word documents you can use [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&displaylang=en)

You may have to write a wrapper in order to use it with your Perl script.

Comment: Do I have to install both the tools listed?

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice (or LibreOffice) has a utility called unoconv that can be used to convert between formats. I believe it does the equivalent of opening the input document in OpenOffice and then saving it as the output format. You say you script already produces opendocument format, so you can try using unoconv to produce a Word document from that.